# Built TypeScript application imports from wrong, src instead of dist, folder

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typeorm

**TLDR;** App builds but tries to import files from src folder instead of dist

I have an Express app that is built with TypeScript.

This is the tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "sourceMap": true,                        /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    "outDir": "dist",                         /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "strict": false,                          /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": false,                   /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    "moduleResolution": "node",               /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    "baseUrl": "./dist",                      /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "node_modules/*"
      ]
    },                                        /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "experimentalDecorators": true,           /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,            /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "custom.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

These are my npm scripts:

```
"scripts": {
      "clean": "rimraf dist/*",
      "dev": "nodemon",
      "tsc": "tsc",
      "start": "node dist/index.js",
      "build": "npm-run-all clean tsc",
   },
```

`npm run build` works fine and all seems nice and dandy, but when I run `npm run start` I get the following error:

```
/app/server/src/entity/Category.ts:1
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, ManyToMany, BaseEntity} from "typeorm";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

The error seems to be that my build for some reason seems to import from the src-folder and not from the build folder. I have no idea what is wrong, any guiding or ideas are appreciated to help me get further.

Comment: My mistake. I had misconfigured TypeORM. When running with absolute paths, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so doing `"start": "node build/index.js"` results in the above behaviour, however if I do the following on the command line:

```
cd build
node index.js
```

It works. So I guess some path is wrong in some module in the application. Will update with more if I find a good way to get this working with NPM scripts.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody else that encounters this problem with Typescript + TypeORM, I encountered it too. The way I solved it was by using `__dirname` to help resolve paths in my TypeORM config.

For example, instead of doing

```js
const connection: DataSourceOptions = {
  ...
  entities: ['src/entities/*.ts', 'dist/entities/*{.ts,.js}'],
}
```

I modified it to

```js
const connection: DataSourceOptions = {
  ...
  entities: [`${__dirname}/../../entities/*{.ts,.js}`],
  migrations: [`${__dirname}/migrations/*{.ts,.js}`],
}
```

Hope this helps!